# onsyncfrompreference not being called

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I'm writing a Firefox add-on and for the `<scale>` XUL element, `onsyncfrompreference` doesn't seem to be called (Firefox 14). Here's my preference:

```xml
<preferences>
      <preference id="pref-sensitivity" name="bbaddon.sensitivity" type="string"/>
      ...
</preferences>
```

and here is the scale:

```xml
<scale min="1" max="100" increment="1" preference="pref-sensitivity"
id="bb-sensitivity"
onsynctopreference="Application.console.log('onsynctopreference called')" 
onsyncfrompreference="Application.console.log('onsyncfrompreference called')" />
```

The logs are just for debugging at the moment, `onsynctopreference` is called no problem as it shows up on the console, but there's no entry from `onsyncfrompreference`. I have a default value defined in `defaults.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [implementation of this feature in `preferences.xml`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/257777cf58fe/toolkit/content/widgets/preferences.xml#l400), `onsyncfrompreference` will only be called for "editable" elements. As to what is considered "editable", you can see that [below](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/257777cf58fe/toolkit/content/widgets/preferences.xml#l510). Some elements are always considered editable, others have to specify `preference-editable="true"` attribute explicitly. In your case it's the latter meaning that your fix would look like this:

```xml
<scale min="1" max="100" increment="1" preference="pref-sensitivity"
  preference-editable="true" id="bb-sensitivity"
  onsynctopreference="Application.console.log('onsynctopreference called')" 
  onsyncfrompreference="Application.console.log('onsyncfrompreference called')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this using Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var loaded = false;
//load preferences
var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefService)
         .getBranch("extensions.bb");
prefs.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch2);

function loadpref() //call this in the prefwindow onload
{
    document.getElementById('bb-sensitivity').value = prefs.getCharPref('sensitivity');  
    loaded = true;
}

function setpref(sensitivity)
{
     if(loaded) //onchange for scale fires before onload for the window
     {
         prefs.setCharPref('sensitivity',sensitivity);
     }
}

</script>
```

and the scale element:

```
<scale min="1" max="100" increment="1" 
    preference="pref-sensitivity" 
    id="bb-sensitivity" 
    onchange="setpref(this.value);"
    />
```

I'll leave this question open for now to see if anyone else can help. I'd still like to do this the 'correct' way.